# how to query in MongoDB based on timestamp

Tags: php, python, mongodb, timestamp, find

I want fire a query in python to find last 24 hrs registered users only.
In my database

```
   I have user profile data as:

    {u'DOB': None,
    u'_id': ObjectId('5906f3b.....'),
    u'active': 0,
    u'bfunc': 0,
    u'city': None,
    u'contact': u'',
```

> u'created': 1493627839,

```
    u'email': u'mymail@demo.c
    u'facebook_id': u'',
    u'fburl': None,
    u'firstname': u'',
    u'gender': None,
    u'group_id': None}
```

Based on created on how can i find last 24 hrs data.
When i convert time-stamp `1493627839` into date it shows as `2017-05-01 14:07:19`

I am doing this but it find 0 values. Am i doing something wrong??? or there is another way.

```
     value = []
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    ltunix = timenow.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") #today
    curTime = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(ltunix,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    gteTime = timenow - datetime.timedelta(days = 10) # last 10th day
    getTimeUnix =gteTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    earTime = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(getTimeUnix,  '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
    cursor = collection.find({
        'created': {'$or':[
            {"$lt": curTime},
            {"$gte": earTime}]
        }
    })
    print cursor
```

I am searching last 10 days in this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For last 24 hours:

```
{'created':{'$lt':datetime.datetime.now(), '$gt':datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=24)}}
```

For last 10 days:

```
{'created':{'$lt':datetime.datetime.now(), '$gt':datetime.datetime.now() - timedelta(days=10)}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the epoch value to store the creation time in the DB. You can use the `calendar` module to convert the datetime objects to epoch values and then do the necessary comparisons.

```
now = calendar.timegm(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple())
then = calendar.timegm((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(hours=24)).timetuple())

result = collection.find({'created': {'$lt':now, '$gte':then}})
```

Comment: i tried this earlier but its timestamp is diffr. So i wonk work in my case. thnkx for responce

Comment: @Vivek, Do you mean to say that the `created` field in the mongo document is not a UNIX epoch value?

Comment: I think so. unix epoch value is `2017-05-08T10:36:34Z` but my value is `2017-05-01 14:07:19`